# Need to get the string in between two patterns in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, pattern-matching, string-matching

I need to match the a pattern i.e. "Commodity Name" and get the string in the next line between the patterns "`<dd>`" "`</dd>`".

Sample Input file:

```
C:\Users\rpm\Desktop\sample.txt:133:    <dt>Commodity Name</dt>
C:\Users\rpm\Desktop\sample.txt:134:    <dd>Grocery</dd>
C:\Users\rpm\Desktop\sample.txt:136:    <dt>IP address</dt>
C:\Users\rpm\Desktop\sample.txt:137:    <dd>XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 8000</dd>
C:\Users\rpm\Desktop\sample.txt:144:    <dt>Commodity Serial #</dt>
C:\Users\rpm\Desktop\sample.txt:145:    <dd>0055500000</dd>
C:\Users\rpm\Desktop\sample.txt:147:    <dt>Client IP</dt>
C:\Users\rpm\Desktop\sample.txt:148:    <dd>xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx</dd>
C:\Users\rpm\Desktop\sample.txt:150:    <dt>Client Logged In As</dt>
C:\Users\rpm\Desktop\sample.txt:151:    <dd>rpm123</dd>
C:\Users\rpm\Desktop\sample.txt:153:    <dt>User is member of</dt>
C:\Users\rpm\Desktop\sample.txt:154:    <dd>BP-RPM\COMD_CSO_ITM-AVAI_Def,BP-RPM\user</dd>
```

Need to match patterns such as

- Commodity Name
- IP address
- Commodity Serial #
- Client IP
- Client Logged In As
- User is member of

and get the values in the next line of the matched patterns between  the tags `<dd> & </dd>`.

Desired output:

```
Grocery | XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 8000 | 0055500000 | xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx | rpm123 | BP-RPM\COMD_CSO_ITM-AVAI_Def,BP-RPM\user
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start to create an `array` defining your keywords:

```
$keywords = @(
    '<dt>Commodity Name</dt>'
    '<dt>IP address</dt>'
    '<dt>Commodity Serial #</dt>'
    '<dt>Client IP</dt>'
    '<dt>Client Logged In As</dt>'
    '<dt>User is member of</dt>'
)
```

Now you can `join` the keywords by an `|` to use it with the `Select-String` cmdlet:

```
$file = 'C:\Users\rpm\Desktop\sample.txt'
$content = Get-Content $file
$content | Select-String -Pattern ($keywords -join '|')
```

This will give you the line number of each matched keyword. Now you can iterate over the result, access the next line by index and crop the `<dd>` pre and `</dd>` postifx:

```
ForEach-Object {
        [regex]::Match($content[$_.LineNumber], '<dd>(.+)</dd>').Groups[1].Value
    }
```

**Regex:**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Output:**

```
Grocery
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 8000
0055500000
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
rpm123
BP-RPM\COMD_CSO_ITM-AVAI_Def,BP-RPM\user
```

Finally you have to join the result by `|` to get the desired output. Here is the whole script:

```
$keywords = @(
    '<dt>Commodity Name</dt>'
    '<dt>IP address</dt>'
    '<dt>Commodity Serial #</dt>'
    '<dt>Client IP</dt>'
    '<dt>Client Logged In As</dt>'
    '<dt>User is member of</dt>'
)

$file = 'C:\Users\rpm\Desktop\sample.txt'
$content = Get-Content $file

($content | Select-String -Pattern ($keywords -join '|') | 
    ForEach-Object {
        [regex]::Match($content[$_.LineNumber], '<dd>(.+)</dd>').Groups[1].Value
    }) -join ' | '
```

**Output:**

```
Grocery | XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 8000 | 0055500000 | xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx | rpm123 | BP-RPM\COMD_CSO_ITM-AVAI_Def,BP-RPM\user
```

Comment: In between is there a motive behind the match using tags as well i.e. `<dt>Commodity Name</dt>` instead of only `Commodity Name`.

Comment: Just to ensure you don't match a `<dt>` Tag containg the string

Comment: Can this same be achieved in vbscript since in some machines in our environment running a powershell script disabled. Instead vbscript is used  in such machines.

Comment: Im sure it can but im not familiar with vb so you probably have to do it yourself.

Comment: Ok...Thanks again :)